# Android studio grayed out memory options for emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to change the memory allocation on the emulator but the options are grayed out:

[image]

I couldn't find anything on SO to answer this question. Any idea why this is?

Comment: You can try other device that doesn't have playstore mark when you are in select hardware page.